# Subquery's WHERE needs fields from main query

Tags: mysql

have been struggling with this for the whole day and would like to ask for help how to make this query happen. My problem is that in INNER JOIN subquery's WHERE parts I need to use matching values from each GC table row being processed and obviously subquery doesnt know nothing about main query that's why it fails. Hopefully you'll catch the idea what i am trying to acomplish here:

```
SET @now=100; #sunix datetime
SELECT a.id, b.maxdate
    FROM GC AS a
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 0 id_group, MAX(dt_active_to) AS maxdate
                FROM GCDeals
                WHERE dt_active_from > a.dt_lastused AND dt_active_from <= @now
                GROUP BY id_group

                UNION ALL
                SELECT 1 id_group, MAX(dt_active_to) AS maxdate
                FROM GCDeals
                WHERE id_group <> 2 AND dt_active_from > a.dt_lastused AND dt_active_from <= @now

                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 id_group, MAX(dt_active_to) AS maxdate
                FROM GCDeals
                WHERE id_group <> 1 AND dt_active_from > a.dt_lastused AND dt_active_from <= @now
                GROUP BY id_group
    ) AS b
    ON a.id_group = b.id_group

    LEFT JOIN GCMsg AS c
    ON a.id = c.id_gc

    WHERE a.is_active = 1 AND a.dt_lastused < @now AND c.id_gc IS NULL
    ORDER BY a.id
```

Thank you

Comment: Your select statement is confusing me. You group by id_group. So your table GCDeals has a column id_group. You group by it, and then regardless if its value you replace it with a zero in all result records. And then you join every GC record with id 0 with all records in GCDeals? Or is id_group not a colum in GCDeals (I think MySQL allows this)? Then why do you group by the literal? Anyway it doesn't look good to me.

Comment: GCDeals has many deals which are assigned to each of these groups 0-unisex, 1-male, 2-female. Table GC has all the customers, where each of the customer belonging to particular group. Tricky part here is that if customer is in group 0, maxdate is being found for 0,1,2 groups (since unisex covers all three groups - itself, male and female), if in 1 - then for 0,1.. if in 2- then 0,2.. That's why inner join subquery actually goes and finds those values the way it does.

Comment: Subquery actually returns me always three rows with two columns: id_group, maxdate. id_group is always 0,1,2 and maxdate is calculated for (0 and 1 and 2) (0 and 1) (0 and 2)

Comment: So GCDeals has an id_group, which you change. Say you have a GC "unisex shirt" with id_group 0, then you join it with three records (0,max_unisex_date), (0,max_male_date) and (0,max_female_date). You don't want to join it with just one record (0,max_all_date)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your second reply. To get three records (0,max_all_date),(1,max_uni_or_male_date) and (2,max_uni_or_female_date), you would have to remove the GROUP BY id_group lines.

Comment: subquery counted my max values right, that is not a problem and without group by i doubt it will do max() thing. Problem starts that i introduce in subquery's WHERE clause value from master query.. that doesnt work no more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I hope I have understood your original SQL now. You want all GC with the last appropriate max date. What you consider appropriate depends both on gc.dt_lastused and on gc.id_group. So rather than joining the tables together, you should select the max date per record in a subquery:

```
select id, 
(
  select max(dt_active_to)
  from gcdeals
  where dt_active_from > gc.dt_lastused and dt_active_from <= @now
  and 
  (
    gc.id_group = 0) 
    or 
    (gc.id_group = 1 and gcdeals.id_group <> 2) 
    or 
    (gc.id_group = 2 and gcdeals.id_group <> 1) 
  )
) as maxdate
from gc
where is_active = 1 and dt_lastused < @now
and id not in (select id_gc from gcmsg)
order by id;
```

EDIT: Here is the same statement using a join, offering to select max(dt_active_from) and min(dt_active_to) in one pass:

```
select gc.id, max(gcd.dt_active_from),  min(gcd.dt_active_to)
from gc
left outer join gcdeals gcd
  on gc.id = gcd.id_gc
  and gcd.dt_active_from > gc.dt_lastused and gcd.dt_active_from <= @now
  and 
  (
    gc.id_group = 0) 
    or 
    (gc.id_group = 1 and gcd.id_group <> 2) 
    or 
    (gc.id_group = 2 and gcd.id_group <> 1) 
  )
where gc.is_active = 1 and gc.dt_lastused < @now
group by gc.id
order by gc.id;
```

You see, once you found out how to select the desired value in a subselect, it is not too hard to change it into a join. You get what you are looking for in two steps. If on the other hand you start with thinking in joins the same task can be quite abstract.

As to the execution plan: Say GC has 1000 active records and there are usually about 10 appropriate matches in GCDeals. Then the first statement selects 1,000 records and uses a loop on each record to access the GCDeals aggregate value. The second statement would just join 1,000 GC records with 10 GCDeals records each, thus getting 10,000 records, then aggregate them to make it 1,000 records again. Maybe the loops are faster, maybe the join. This depends. But, say, GC has one million active records and on each record you expect 1000 GCDeals matches, then the first statement may be quite slow having to loop so many times. But the second statement will create a billion intermediate records which can cause memory problems and either lead to very slow execution, too, or even lead to an unsufficient memory error. So it's just good to know that both techniques are available.

Comment: Thanks, will give this one a try and see whether it works or not :) Fingers crossed

Comment: It actually works.. except for one small missing "(" which is not relevant of course here. Now I see the logics behind this.. yeah, totally different way of thinking than my initial approach. Thanks a lot, and truly appreciate your time!

Comment: One more question... if i would like to modify the beginning of the query like this: SELECT id, 
(
  SELECT MAX(dt_active_from), MIN(dt_active_to)... it will not allow me of course. Would it be appropriate to include two idential constructions to retrieve MAX(dt_active_from) and another one for MIN(dt_active_to)? Wouldnt performance suffer a lot?

Comment: You are right. This is good for one field, but once you need two, you will do the work twice. I am adding a statement where you join the tables. You will see that the statements look quite similar, but there is usually a big difference in how the data gets accessed. When tables are big and you get a lot of gcdeals matches for each gc record then intermediate data may get huge and cause problems. But from your description I gather that this is not the case, so the second statement should be faster.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten for adding more into this! Right, there will not be many GCDeals records (probably 10-20), however GC (where the clients are stored) is going to be up to 100k or something. Which approach would your recommend for such size?

Comment: When needing more than one value, I would use the latter (the one with the join), so not to do the same thing twice. Only when being confronted then with performance problems, I would try the former.